# File explorer in sqlite database of android studio

Tags: android, sqlite

I need to find the data stored in sqlite databased on Android Studio. When I use tools-> android -> android device monitor to open file explore, I got an error "android device monitor is already launched". I do not know how to figure it out. Is there other method to obtain the data file in sqlite database? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows operating system, Android Studio open in Administrative Mode (Run as administrator)

Comment: Unfortunately, I use Mac OS... Is there any way to solve the problem?